# How to add Datetimepicker in ng2-smart-table

Tags: datetimepicker, ng2-smart-table

I wanted to add a `datetimepicker` component to the ng2-smart-table component.
All I'm able to do right now is add a `datepicker`, but I want to add time in that as well.

I have tried with some owl-date-time component.
but it's messing up the entire window.

**HTML file**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input
        [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt"
        [(ngModel)]="inputModel"
        placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
        [min]='min' [max]='max'
        readonly
        class="form-control">
</div>
<owl-date-time #dt [stepMinute]="15" [hour12Timer]='true' (afterPickerClosed)="onChange()"></owl-date-time>


**.ts file**

  @Input() placeholder: string = 'Choose a Date/Time';

  @Input() min: Date; // Defaults to now(rounded down to the nearest 15 minute mark)

  @Input() max: Date; // Defaults to 1 month after the min

  stringValue;
  inputModel: Date;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(!this.min) {
      this.min = new Date();
      this.min.setMinutes(Math.floor(this.min.getMinutes() / 15) * 15 );
    }

    if(!this.max) {
      this.max = new Date(this.min);
      this.max.setFullYear(this.min.getFullYear() + 1);
    }

    if(this.cell.newValue) {
      let cellValue = new Date(this.cell.newValue);
      if(cellValue.getTime() >= this.min.getTime() && cellValue.getTime() <= this.max.getTime()) {
        this.inputModel = cellValue;
        this.cell.newValue = this.inputModel.toISOString();
      }
    }

    if(!this.inputModel) {
      this.inputModel = this.min;
      this.cell.newValue = this.inputModel.toISOString();
    }
  }

  onChange() {
    if(this.inputModel) {
      this.cell.newValue = this.inputModel.toISOString();
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `{{value | date:'short'}}`,
})
export class SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent implements ViewCell, OnInit {
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() rowData: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
```

I want a date-time-picker in ng2-smart-table to choose a date and time of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it!!
Just follow this 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-date-picker-smart-table-tjvgbe .

Don't forget to add the styles in the angular.json file, just like the stackblitz link.